# I am getting NullPointerExecption in my Java program

Tags: java, exception, java-8, nullpointerexception

I just started learning java and I'm trying to count the number of times a word appeared in a string which I passed it. I'm using the HashMap class, the words I pass are the key and their count is the value. I can't figure out why I keep getting a NPE exception in the counter, the for loop looks right to me, did I use the split function incorrectly?

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class WordCount {

    private HashMap<String,Integer> map;

    public WordCount() {
        map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    }

    public WordCount(String words) {
        String[] list = words.split(",");

        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if(!map.containsKey(list[i]))  {
                map.put(list[i],1);
            } else {
                map.put(list[i],map.get(list[i])+1);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addWord(String toAdd) {
        if(!map.containsKey(toAdd)) {
            map.put(toAdd,1);
        } else {
            map.put(toAdd,map.get(toAdd)+1);
        }
    }

    public void startOver() {
        if(map.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        } else {
            for(String s: map.keySet()) {
                map.remove(s);
        }
    }
}

public int countWord(String word) {
    return map.get(word);
}


}
```

/***************************************/

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "hello,bye,how,are,you,ok";
        WordCount wordC = new WordCount(s);

        System.out.println("Number of Words: " + wordC.countWord("how"));
    }

}
```

Comment: The map is not being initialized until `map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();` which is in the zero paramater constrcutor, which is **not** being called

Comment: `public WordCount(String words)` constructor isn't calling the `public WordCount()`  constructor, therefore `map` is `null`

Comment: Add `this()` at the first line of `public WordCount(String words) {` constructor.

Comment: An option would be adding an instantiation to your class attribute: `private HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

Comment: You have put the hashmap initialisation in the wrong constructor.

Comment: There is no real need to have two constructors here: only the `()` one is needed to create the instance in a valid state (which is the purpose of a constructor); there other is really just a convenience to say "create an instance, and add data to it". A better approach would be to remove the second, and add a static factory method which literally does create the instance and invoke add repeatedly, then return the instance. (Additionally, `map.merge` is an easier way to implement the `addWord` method).